# LLVM compile: recipe for target '../lib/IR/Release+Asserts/Intrinsics.gen.tmp' failed

Tags: c++, makefile, llvm, llvm-ir

I use some legacy code using `llvm 3.6.2`, so I try to build this version of llvm from source code.

I use these two commands:

```
$ ./configure --enable-assertions
$ make
```

And got the following error (without `enable-assertions` got same):

```
[2]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/llvm-lit'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/not'
llvm[2]: Compiling not.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[2]: Linking Release+Asserts executable not (without symbols)
llvm[2]: ======= Finished Linking Release+Asserts Executable not (without symbols)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/not'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest/googletest'
llvm[3]: Compiling src/gtest-all.cc for Release+Asserts build
llvm[3]: Building Release+Asserts Archive Library libgtest.a
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest/googletest'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest/UnitTestMain'
llvm[3]: Compiling TestMain.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[3]: Building Release+Asserts Archive Library libgtest_main.a
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest/UnitTestMain'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils/unittest'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/utils'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/lib/IR'
llvm[1]: Building Intrinsics.gen.tmp from Intrinsics.td
0  llvm-tblgen     0x0000000000576a58
1  llvm-tblgen     0x00000000005780ab
2  libpthread.so.0 0x0000153db3008390
3  llvm-tblgen     0x000000000053382e
4  llvm-tblgen     0x0000000000526a76
5  libc.so.6       0x0000153db1f7f830 __libc_start_main + 240
6  llvm-tblgen     0x00000000004053c9
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-tblgen -I /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/lib/IR -I /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/include -I /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/include -I /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/lib/Target /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.td -o /home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/lib/IR/Release+Asserts/Intrinsics.gen.tmp -gen-intrinsic 
Makefile:23: recipe for target '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/lib/IR/Release+Asserts/Intrinsics.gen.tmp' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/lib/IR/Release+Asserts/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm-build/lib/IR'
/home/zhangysh1995/packages/llvm/Makefile.rules:873: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I searched for solutions but there is no one working.

Comment: This problem still unsolved, any comments is welcome.

Comment: What not try it out with `CMake`?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer It works for `LLVM`, but for my purpose, another tool using `LLVM` must use the same compilation method. The `CMake` doesn't work well for my tool, so I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by using `clang/clang++` as the compiler, which could be resolved if the compiler is `gcc`.

However, it is shown [here](https://releases.llvm.org/3.6.2/docs/GettingStarted.html) in the documentation, `clang` is supported.